# Where has all my music gone? I can't find it on my iMac

Tags: macos, itunes, imac, music

I have all my music in iTunes on my old iMac. Or I did have. I created several playlists years ago and each of them had 30-50 songs in them. Tonight I opened iTunes and clicked on the playlist and each one had only 3 or 4 songs. Where could all my music have gone?  I haven't changed systems or done anything like that recently. I'm running High Sierra.

Comment: Are the actual files missing from your filesystem or just the playlists? Do you have a Time Machine backup? If yes, you could try restoring from an earlier time.

Comment: I don't recall all the tunes in my playlists but I can't seem to find much of my music anywhere in iTunes.  Time machine doesn't work on my computer so no I don't have an older backup. i backup now using Backblaze but i'm sure it overwrites every backup.

Comment: If the only backup you have is a backup software that overwrites the previous backup then IMO it's about worthless. If you do not maintain proper backups, then I'm not sure what you expect in a situation such as this! Check the filesystem outside of iTunes and see if you music exists in full. E.g. `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/..` and go from there.

Comment: I didn't expect anything. I was hoping that tunes were written somewhere else like iCloud drive or that iTune setting was causing this confusion.  Maybe someone would know.  As far as my backups, Time Machine won't work after using it faithfully for many years.  I was told it was because my backup drive was formated APFS.  I did recall that I'm also using Carbon Copty Cloner so maybe i'll try to extract something from that.

Comment: If it was written somewhere else, we wouldn't know that.  You can put your iTunes library anywhere you want.  On a different note, did you have an iTunes subscription that expired?

Comment: I had iTunes Match expire.  But I found most or all of my music. It apparently got transferred to my iPad Pro.  When i check the playlists there they all have many tunes in them.  So I'll be answering my own question.

Comment: @Allan, there is no way i copied the library or songs to my iPad so some setting somewhere must have triggered this.

Comment: I didn't say your iPad and there are infinite locations you could have copied it to.  There's no setting that will move your music arbitrarily from where you have it to somewhere else.  If it's not in the location you put it in or in the default location `~/Music/iTunes...` then nobody here could possibly know where your Music is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching elsewhere for my music I decided to check my iPad Pro. My music appears to have gotten transferred to my iPad. I feel confident I didn't intentionally do this so some settings on my iPad or iMac must have triggered moving my music to my iPad. My iMac hard drive is about full and my iPad has 200 GB free. I don't know if that matters.